# PDFTron Migrate with Angularjs Issue

Tags: angularjs, pdftron

I'm trying to use PDFTron webviewer with angularjs
i have got error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHashParam' of undefined  at Module. (webviewer-ui.min.js:68)"

Comment: Is this still an issue for you, or did Wanbo's answer work for you? An update would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this guide - https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/get-started/angular/, which also includes sample of integrating WebViewer into Angular project. Also, make sure the versions of Core and UI are matched.